# Error when using UpgradeModule upgrading from AngularJS 1.5 to Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I've been following the Angular upgrade guide to create a hybrid AngularJS/Angular app, but I'm falling at the first hurdle.

I get the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppModule: (?).`

Here's my `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule
    ]
})

export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {}

    ngDoBootstrap() {
        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['MyApp'], { strictDi: true });
    }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

It's worth pointing out that I'm using webpack, and I've tried aliasing the `@angular/upgrade/static` package as follows:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
        "@angular/upgrade/static": "@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js"
    }
},
```

But this doesn't seem to help at all.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: *side note* - why not use `angular-cli` instead of webpack?

Comment: @Igor I'm using Laravel Mix, and I figured it just made sense to run it through there

Comment: Mine looks pretty much the same, but I'm using the cli. I would see if you can spawn off a test project and get it working with the cli quickly. If it works then it's probably something wrong with your webpack config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out through a combination of [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-started-with-ngupgrade-going-from-angularjs-to-angular), and tweaking my `tsconfig` to match one generated by angular-cli.

Comment: It would be nice, if you could point out the relevant parts in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the specific part of the article [How To Upgrade from AngularJS to Angular with ngUpgrade](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-from-angularjs-to-angular-with-ngupgrade) which helped was to import `zone.js` and `reflect-metadata`:

```js
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is so difficult to find, I just spent the last 2 days trying to figure this out. Now to figure out why it doesn't actually bootstrap my AngularJS app.... at least I'm no longer getting the OP's error.